# NSTableView notification when column resizing has finished?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

With an NSTableview I can subscribe to the `NSTableViewColumnDidResizeNotification` to get events of a column being resized:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(tableColumnsResized)
                                             name: NSTableViewColumnDidResizeNotification
                                           object: dataTableView];
```

However, I'm looking to only get a notification once the resizing has finished (so that I can save some details). If I run the code every notification, then the column resizing stutters a bit. This is why I would like to only be notified when the resizing has finished.

Any suggestions how how I could do this?

Comment: According to the docs: `NSTableViewColumnDidResizeNotification` should already do what you want: "Posted whenever a column is resized in an NSTableView object".

Comment: It currently posts the notification for every pixel of movement. I want to be only notified when it is finished.

Comment: not sure how things were back in 2013, but today, NSTableViewColumnDidResizeNotification certainly triggers only when resize has finished. The accepted answer is awful btw... and even if the notification was erroneously sent on every mouse drag event in 2013, the accepted solution would compute after 0.5 seconds after mouse has stopped moving, even though the mousebutton has  not been released, so the dragging has not actually finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a short timer whenever you receive the resize notification, cancelling any previous timer.  You can then perform your final action in the *timer fired* method:

.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSView
{
    NSTimer *_columnResizeTimer;
}

@end
```

.m:

```
// Private Methods
@implementation MyClass ()

- (void)_columnResized:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_columnResizeTimer invalidate];
    _columnResizeTimer = nil;

    // If using MRR:
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)tableViewColumnDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [_columnResizeTimer invalidate];
    _columnResizeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(_columnResized:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:NO];
}

- (void)_columnResized:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [_columnResizeTimer invalidate];
    _columnResizeTimer = nil;

    // Do stuff on column resize
}

@end
```

(This code is untested and possibly buggy).

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe. This should work great. I'm going to leave the question unanswered for a few days just to see what other options come in as it does seem a bit hacky, but otherwise I will choose this!

Comment: @Zenox I agree; it's horrible, but seems to be a commonly used mechanism to defer one-time processing of rapid events.